# Like take long time on inner join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to inner join 2 tables using like operator but the join statement takes a long time (more than 3 hours) each table have round 45000 records
When I replace like operator with = operator the inner join take 30 seconds only but I need to use like operator to return the correct result so I need a suitable alternative for like operator

```
    create table #SheetTransaction  
    (
            ID                  INT             IDENTITY(1,1) ,
            trx_date            NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            trx_type            NVARCHAR(250)   COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            trx_debit           NUMERIC(15, 3)  NULL,
            trx_credit          NUMERIC(15, 3)  NULL,
            check_no            VARCHAR(15)     COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            trx_description     NVARCHAR(255)   COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            insurance_no        NVARCHAR(50)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            deposit_date        NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            transfer_date       NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            creditor_no         NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            transfer_no         NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            daily_date          NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            match_status        NUMERIC(1, 0)   NULL,
            old_or_new_reco     NUMERIC(1, 0)   NULL,
            ref_id              INT             NULL,
            trx_remain_amt      NUMERIC(15,3)   NULL,
            match_reason        NVARCHAR(255)  COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            ref_trx_id          INT             NULL,
            ref_line_ser        NUMERIC(8,0)    NULL,
            tab_id              NUMERIC(5,0)    NULL   
    )

    CREATE INDEX tempindex0 ON #SheetTransaction (trx_description)


    create table #SysTransaction  
    (
            ID                  INT             IDENTITY(1,1) ,
            trx_date            NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            trx_type            NVARCHAR(250)   COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            trx_debit           NUMERIC(15, 3)  NULL,
            trx_credit          NUMERIC(15, 3)  NULL,
            check_no            VARCHAR(15)     COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            trx_description     NVARCHAR(255)   COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            insurance_no        NVARCHAR(50)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            deposit_date        NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            transfer_date       NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            creditor_no         NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            transfer_no         NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            daily_date          NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            match_status        NUMERIC(1, 0)   NULL,
            old_or_new_reco     NUMERIC(1, 0)   NULL,
            ref_id              INT             NULL,
            trx_remain_amt      NUMERIC(15,3)   NULL,
            match_reason        NVARCHAR(255)  COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NULL,
            ref_trx_id          INT             NULL,
            ref_line_ser        NUMERIC(8,0)    NULL,
            tab_id              NUMERIC(5,0)    NULL,
            ref_fact_ser        NUMERIC(16,0)   NULL   
    )

    CREATE INDEX tempindex1 ON #SysTransaction (trx_description)

   

    SELECT BnkTbl.ID,SysTbl.ID
    FROM #SheetTransaction BnkTbl
    INNER JOIN #SysTransaction SysTbl
    ON  SysTbl.trx_debit = BnkTbl.trx_credit 
    AND SysTbl.trx_credit = BnkTbl.trx_debit 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(BnkTbl.trx_description,''))) like ('%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(SysTbl.insurance_no,''))) + '%')  
    AND len(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(SysTbl.insurance_no,'')))) > 0
    AND len(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(BnkTbl.trx_description,'')))) > 0
```

[The execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1hkyA4nv)

[Small DB Backup -30 MB- contains the 2 tables filled with sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZAB6Un8P2_bWwI7jCDR6rqQLlHc9HFMv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's almost impossible to help if you don't give us actual SQL statements.

Comment: Show table schemas, commands used, and current execution plan reported by SQL Server.

Comment: the code has been added

Comment: It's not just the `LIKE` that is the problem, the entire statement isn't SARGable. Applying functions to your columns; such as `ISNULL`, `LEN`, `TRIM` as well has giving your expression in a `LIKE` a **leading** wildcard all mean that the query isn't SARGable meaning no amount of indexes are going to help.

Comment: *Fortunately* you can fix a clause like `len(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(BnkTbl.trx_description,'')))) > 0 ` as simply `BnkTbl.trx_description <> ''` would be identical. `NULL` does not equal `''`, and a string like `'    '` *does* equal `''`, as trailing spaces are ignored when determining string equality; in a string made up entirely of white space, all the characters are effectively trailing spaces. Those 2 `LEN` clauses (which you should replace) should also probably be in the `WHERE`, not the `ON`.

Comment: For the `LIKE`, without sample data we have no chance of guessing if we can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to @Larnu's comment - the issues and approach for the first step are fundamentally the same.

Basically, for the first step, it would be good to

- Move the more complex conditions to the WHERE clause rather than the JOIN (I don't know why, but it often runs better - and is definitely easier to read in my opinion)
- Simplify the complex conditions

Moving the complex clauses to the WHERE clause looks like this

```
SELECT      BnkTbl.ID,SysTbl.ID
    FROM    #SheetTransaction BnkTbl
            INNER JOIN #SysTransaction SysTbl
                ON  SysTbl.trx_debit = BnkTbl.trx_credit 
                AND SysTbl.trx_credit = BnkTbl.trx_debit
    WHERE   LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(BnkTbl.trx_description,''))) 
                like ('%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(SysTbl.insurance_no,''))) + '%')  
            AND len(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(SysTbl.insurance_no,'')))) > 0
            AND len(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(BnkTbl.trx_description,'')))) > 0
```

Now, to simplify the above

- The `LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL...` expressions are fundamentally checking that the relevant column a) is not NULL, and b) is not just spaces. Therefore, you can simplify these to be

```
            AND LTRIM(SysTbl.insurance_no) > ''
            AND LTRIM(BnkTbl.trx_description) > ''
```

However, we can embed the check on BnkTbl.trx_description into the first part of the WHERE clause (checking that BnkTbl.trx_description is like the insurance number) - meaning we can get rid of the check for that above.

Therefore, the following statement should provide the same result and should be a somewhat faster because less calculation required

```
SELECT      BnkTbl.ID,SysTbl.ID
    FROM    #SheetTransaction BnkTbl
            INNER JOIN #SysTransaction SysTbl
                ON  SysTbl.trx_debit = BnkTbl.trx_credit 
                AND SysTbl.trx_credit = BnkTbl.trx_debit
    WHERE   BnkTbl.trx_description like '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SysTbl.insurance_no)) + '%'
            AND LTRIM(SysTbl.insurance_no) > ''
```

The logic is

- The second part of the WHERE clause ensures that SysTbl.insurance_no has a value (not NULL and not blank)
- The first part of the WHERE clause ensures that BnkTbl.trx_description is not NULL and not blank (as it must be `LIKE % + SysTbl.insurance_no + %`, and SysTbl.insurance_no is also not NULL and not blank)

---

Part 2 of the answer is to add indexes to help the join.

The indexes

- make the join easier (pre-sorted on the relevant fields joined)
- only include the data you need, to make reads faster (e.g., make these as 'covering indexes')

If you create these two indexes before running the SELECT statement, it should also run a lot faster

```
CREATE INDEX #tempindex0_2 ON #SheetTransaction (trx_credit, trx_debit, ID) INCLUDE (trx_description);
CREATE INDEX #tempindex1_2 ON #SysTransaction (trx_debit, trx_credit, ID) INCLUDE (insurance_no);
```

Note that the two indexes are both on trx_debit and trx_credit, but they are in opposite orders. This is so that the indexes will be sorted in the orders to help with the join. It doesn't matter *which* one comes first in which index; just that they need to be in the opposite order

- The first part of the join is on `SysTbl.trx_debit = BnkTbl.trx_credit` therefore these should be the first fields in their relevant indexes; similarly, the second part of the join is `SysTbl.trx_credit = BnkTbl.trx_debit` so that becomes the second field in each of the indexes. Or vice-versa
- Including the IDs and the description/insurance numbers means that the calculations can be done with the indexes only - not needing to go back to the base table to get extra data (e.g., these are covering indexes).

Comment: Still take a long time

Comment: Could you get the Actual execution plan for the query and put into Brent Ozar's [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) - instructions are included on the site. Note that the Actual execution plan is better than the Estimated execution plan as we can see times etc.

Comment: Here are small backup contains only 2 tables filled with data        https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZAB6Un8P2_bWwI7jCDR6rqQLlHc9HFMv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I had a look and a go at the data. The indexes above helped (note - they weren't on the data) however it is still painfully slow. The LIKE really slows it down. My suggestion is, for each row in both tables, determine the exact `insurance_no` (e.g., clean it from SysTbl and create it in BnkTbl from `trx_description`). A lot of the trx_descriptions are of the same format, so you should hopefully be able to do it. Then you can join on the cleaned insurance_no fields without the need for a LIKE. I'm sorry - past that I couldn't make it run better.